# A subset of a non measurable set is always non measurable?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

This probably isnt true but I am having difficulties proving this function to be non measurable: First off I have that $E$ is an non measurable set. and $E=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k$

and 
$$f(x)= \begin{cases} k\ ; \ \ \  x\in E_k \\ 1\ ; \ \ \ x  \notin E\end{cases} $$
I have to question its measurability.

Since $E$ is non measurable then at least one $E_k$ must be non measurable. Say that index is $l$. It is easy to prove that $E$ is nonmeasurable when $l\neq 1$ but when it is, I don't know what to do. This is how I went about proving that it wasnt measurable for $l\neq 1$ and tried for $l=1$.

Lets assume that f(x) is measurable.Then:
$$A=\{x\in X | f(x) \geq l\} \\ B=\{x\in X | f(x) \leq l\} \\ A \cap B=\{x \in X| f(x)=l\}$$ are measurable.
and $A \cap B=E_l$ , and $E_l$ being not measurable we conclude a contradiction. But when $l=1$ we have $A \cap B=E^c \cap E_1$. This is different. I know nothing about this set with confidece, and currently cannot conclude it's non measurability . Thoughts?

Comment: Well, actually a counterexample can be constructed using exactly what you say. For example, consider $E_1$ a non measurable set contained in the interval $(- \infty , -1)$, and for $k \ge 2$ let $E_k= (k-1, k)$. It is clear that $f$ defined by the formula you give is measurable.

Comment: (1) There are Lebesgue-nonmeasurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.  (2)  Singletons are Lebesgue-measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: or just take $\emptyset$

Comment: $\{\}$ is a subset of every set, and last I checked it was measurable :)